# Help with a Swing JFrame with 3 comboboxes and a vector variable

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jframe

I created a Swing `JFrame` with 3 comboboxes and a vector variable to populate them, but all comboboxes are empty on execution of code. Can someone tell me what is wrong.

```
public class Notes extends JFrame {

    JFrame jf;
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<Integer>();
    int i;
    Integer x;
    Dimension d = new Dimension(40, 12);

    Notes() {

        jf = new JFrame("ComboBox Demo");

        for (i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
            x = new Integer(i);
            v.add(x);
        }

        JComboBox date = new JComboBox(v);
        v.removeAllElements();



        for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            x = new Integer(i);
            v.add(x);
        }

        JComboBox month = new JComboBox(v);
        v.removeAllElements();


        for (i = 2011; i <= 2020; i++) {
            x = new Integer(i);
            v.add(x);
        }

        JComboBox year = new JComboBox(v);
        v.removeAllElements();


        date.setSize(d);
        month.setSize(d);
        year.setSize(d);

        jp.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 5, 5));
        jp.add(date);
        jp.add(month);
        jp.add(year);

        jf.add(jp, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        jf.setSize(300, 300);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new Notes();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is no need to use ".pls help" in subject of the question.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty obvious because you are removing all elements of your vector:

```
v.removeAllElements(); //that's wrong
```

When you pass v to your JComboBox constructor, the combobox doesn't copy each value but references the Vector you gave to it. So if you remove the elements from that vector, you'll see an empty combo box.

If you were doing this to reuse v variable after each cicle substitute the wrong lines above  with :

```
v = new Vector<Integer>();
```

Comment: Obviously. And obviously there are many things wrong with this code snippet. Perhaps your time would be more well-spent if you took the time to explain why "that's wrong", and what he should be doing instead.

Comment: @little bunny foo foo: give me at least the time to complete my answer. Btw, what's wrong with my code snippet?

Comment: @Overbose, I was referring to OP's code snippet, not yours.

Comment: correct advice how to remove all elements from 'Vector', that's pre-dinosaurus API, and another option(s) doesn't exist +1

Comment: +1 @mKorble's right about `java.util.Vector`. Otherwise, it's a good answer, so I tried to salvage the question.